# Sum up all exception in one return

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-boot

I developped an application spring-boot for managing useres. I need to handle the exceptions like this object:

```
{
  "general_errors": "service_unavailable"
  "errors": [
    {
      "key": "email",
      "value": "is empty"
    },
    {
      "key": "postal_code",
      "value": "required"
    }
  ]
}
```

For example in my service side when a validation is KO I need to add that to the list of errors. Somthing like that:

```
if (email == null ) 
 errors.addToErrorList("email", "is empty"
...
```

then if there is a runtime exception

```
try {
...
}catch (InterruptedException e){
 errors.addgeneral("general_errors", e.getMessage());
}
```

Would you have any ideas how I can do that ?

I tried with @ControllerAdvice But I don't khnow how I can implement that

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = BaseException.class)
    public ErrorResponseWrapper handleBaseException(BaseException e) {
        ErrorResponseWrapper error = new ErrorResponseWrapper();
        // error.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        return error;
    }
```

Best regards

Comment: Can't you just use standard JSR303 validation. The example https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/ BindingResult contains all found errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly handle validation errors, you can use [JSR-303](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/) which comes with [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) web. For example, let's say you have a controller that has two parameters `postalCode` and `email`. You could create an object called `ApiParameters`:

```
public class ApiParameters {
    @NotNull(message = "is empty")
    @Email(message = "is not an email")
    private String email;
    @NotNull(message = "is required")
    private String postalCode;

    public ApiParameters() {
    }

    // Getters + Setters
}
```

> The [`@NotNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) and [`@Email`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Email.html) annotations are validation annotations (`@Email` is from Hibernate though).

Now, at your controller, you can now put:

```
@GetMapping
public String doStuff(@Valid ApiParameters parameters) {
    // ...
}
```

Due to the `@Valid` annotation, if any of the parameters are wrong, then a [`BindException`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindException.html) is thrown, which you can catch in a controller advice class, like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(BindException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorResponse errorResponse(BindException ex) {
        return new ErrorResponse("Validation failed", ex.getFieldErrors()
            .stream()
            .map(err -> new SpecificError(err.getField(), err.getDefaultMessage()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

What happens here is that I call the `getFieldErrors()` method of the `BindException`, which contains a list of all errors. Then I map those to the response classes that resemble the response you want (`ErrorResponse` and `SpecificErorr`):

```
public class ErrorResponse {
    @JsonProperty("general_errors")
    private String generalErrors;
    private List<SpecificError> errors;

    public ErrorResponse(String generalErrors, List<SpecificError> errors) {
        this.generalErrors = generalErrors;
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public String getGeneralErrors() {
        return generalErrors;
    }

    public List<SpecificError> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }
}

public class SpecificError {
    private String key;
    private String value;

    public SpecificError(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

If you call your API with insufficient parameters, you will now get the following JSON response:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "key": "postalCode",
            "value": "is required"
        },
        {
            "key": "email",
            "value": "is empty"
        }
    ],
    "general_errors": "Validation failed"
}
```

Similar to this, you can catch `RuntimeException`s as well:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ErrorResponse errorResponse(RuntimeException ex) {
    return new ErrorResponse(ex.getMessage(), null);
}
```

However, if you want to combine both, you'll have to manually call the validator, because the way this works is that as soon as an exception is throw, it will stop processing the method.

This means that if your method would throw a `RuntimeException`, it will not happen if a validation error was already thrown.

Comment: Thanks @g00glen00b I will test that

Comment: I implemented your example but how I can throw/catch the exception. I tried this `throw new ErrorHandler ();`  but it doesn't work

Comment: @Victor you don't have to throw `ErrorHandler`? And why would you try to catch an exception?

Comment: I nned when the runtime exception is thrown do some action.   For example when create user is Ko I want to send a message in kafka bus to inform other service that the creation is Ko

Comment: I test the example but the return response is not format like I want spring return me something like  `{
  "timestamp": 1497431366648,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException",
  "errors": [
    {
      "codes": [
        "NotNull.customerInfo.civility",
        "NotNull.civility",
        "NotNull.java.lang.String",
        "NotNull"
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "codes": [
            "customerInfo.civility",
            "civility"
          ],`

Comment: @Victor you may want to create an `ExceptionHandler` for the `MethodArgumentNotValidException` as well. From there it's similar to how I implemented the `BindException`, you just have to use `ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()` to get (and map) the field errors.

Comment: thanks  @g00glen00b it works. Do you have an idea how I can use diffrent validation for example when I create user password is mandatory but when I update him no. I have another problem is that I have some fields that depends on other for example if the user has status 'professional' the field phoneNumber is mandatory

Comment: @Victor for fields depending on each other you can create a custom validator on class level. Writing a custom validator involves creating an annotation, eg. `@ValidProfessional` (on `TYPE`/ `ANNOTATION_TYPE` level) and then you can create a bean that implements `ConstraintValidator<ValidProfessional, YourModelClass>`.

Comment: @Victor fields depending on the use case are a bit more difficult. You have a few approaches, like creating a custom validator on class level that checks the `password` field and is able to verify if the object is a new/updated one (you could use the ID of the object for example, if it's new, perhaps it has no ID). Another solution is to create a subclass, for example `UnregisteredUser` and apply the `@NotNull` on the getter of `getPassword()`. Be aware though, validation annotations are cumulative, so the parent class should only contain validations that are applicable to all use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I really like this pattern. This is my implementation:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);


    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorWrapper> RunTimeException(RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOG.error("Error: {}", e.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorWrapper>(new ErrorWrapper(e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<List<ValidationError>> validationExceptionHandle(ValidationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<ValidationError>>(e.getErrors(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

And here is my validation method:

```
private void validate(VisitTO to) {
    List<ValidationError> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    Visit visit = new Visit();

    if (to.getDate() == null) {
        LOG.error("Date was null.");
        errors.add(new ValidationError("date", MAY_NOT_BE_NULL));
    } else {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(to.getDate());
        if (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 15 || cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > 18) {
            errors.add(new ValidationError("date", NOT_ALLOWED));
        }
        to.setDate(roundTime(to.getDate()));
    }
    if (to.getId() != null) {
        LOG.error("Id wasn't null.");
        errors.add(new ValidationError("id", NOT_ALLOWED));
    }
    if (to.getUserUuid() == null) {
        LOG.error("UUID was null.");
        errors.add(new ValidationError("user.uuid", MAY_NOT_BE_NULL));
    } else {
        if (!LoggedUserUtils.isDoctor(LoggedUserUtils.getLoggedUser())) {
            if (!to.getUserUuid().equals(LoggedUserUtils.getLoggedUser().getPesel())) {
                throw new SecurityException();
            }
        }
    }
    if (to.getCompleted() == null ) {
        LOG.error("Completed was null.");
        errors.add(new ValidationError("completed", MAY_NOT_BE_NULL));
    }
    if (userRepository.findByPesel(to.getUserUuid()) == null) {
        LOG.error("User not found.");
        errors.add(new ValidationError("pesel", NO_SUCH_USER));
    }

    if (!errors.isEmpty()){
        throw new ValidationException(errors);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why do you like the approach? Hard to maintain, hard to localize or provide custom messages, hard to combine, need manual processing on UI. JSR303 based on annotations does this automatically and provides plenty of usefull things

Comment: In my opinion it's perfect e.g. for bulk uploads, when you have to list all errors to the user, so he can repair the file. Returning list of errors in a json is easy to use on front-end

Comment: @xenteros JSR303 is just an easy way to be able to avoid all these `if()` statements. It still allows you to send a list of errors in a JSON.